# Django export excel file without saving it

Tags: python, django, excel

Currently I am exporting an excel file, however, before it gets exported, I create an xls file on the host machine. To create the excel file, I use `tablib`. My export view looks like this:

```py
@login_required
def export_xls(request):
    # some irrelevant code

    data = convert_json_to_dataset(json_data)

    table = data.export('xls')
    with open('/tmp/students.xls', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(table)

    response = FileResponse(open('/tmp/students.xls', 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename="test.xls")

    return response
```

What I am trying to achieve is to avoid writing always to `/tmp/students.xls`. I tried using `BytesIO`, however that did not work out.

```py
@login_required
def export_xls(request):
    # some irrelevant code

    data = convert_json_to_dataset(json_data)

    table = data.export('xls')
    buffer = BytesIO()
    
    buffer.write(table)

    response = FileResponse(buffer.read(), as_attachment=True, filename="test.xls")

    return response
```

Currently I am always overwriting the file, however, I will change the naming of the file and that will cause multiple files to be created, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `that did not work out` thing? What error/problem do you get? On which line does it occur?

Comment: Yes, that would have been a smart thing to do. The content was `b''`, which I figured out I need to use `buffer.seek(0)`, however, django's `FileResponse` could not set the content type correctly, so I used `response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'`, which produced an excel file, however, the browser already warned me it seems off and it could be corrupted, and the data inside where just random numbers.

Comment: Looks like you don't need the `read()` since `FileResponse` expects a file-like object. And yes, you probably have to add `seek(0)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Without `read()` it works :). Thanks! However, maybe a bit unrelated, but the `Content-Disposition` header is not being set, so the file has a weird name when downloaded.